# Switch python versions using pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv

Im trying to switch to python 2.715. I do:

```
pyenv versions
```

I see:

```
  system
* 2.7.15 (set by /Users/me/.pyenv/version)
  3.7.2
  3.7.2/envs/env_name
  3.8.0
  env_name
```

I then do:

```
python --version
```

Yet I get the result:

```
Python 3.9.7
```

How can I switch to python 2.7.15?

Comment: It seems you have to use `pyenv local 2.7.15`. I saw the info [here](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#specifying-your-python-version) and hope is right

Answer (score 2):

[You need to add the shim to your system PATH](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv)

Edit your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, and add

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Worth pointing out that Python2 is EOL, and you really shouldn't be using it.